# Eigenvalue and eigenvector for an operator applied to harmonic homogeneous polynomials

Tags: polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

"Let $p(x_1,....,x_n)$ be a harmonic homogeneous polynomial of degree $\ell$, then $(x_1^2+...+x_n^2)^mp(x)$ is an eigenvector of the operator $|x|^2 \Delta = \sum_{i=1}^n|x|^2 \cdot \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2}$." 
 I would like to calculate the eigenvalues for every m = 0,1,2,3,... I have tried to do that but I get something else every time I calculate it. My question now is what the eigenvalue is and how you can calculate it.

Comment: Isn't it $|x|^2 \Delta = \sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^2 \cdot \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2}$ ? (I have replaced the second occurence of $|x|^2$ by $|x_i|^2$)

Comment: Do we agree that a harmonic homogeneous polynomial of degree one is a linear form $\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix_i$ ?

Comment: But maybe I have misread letter spelled "ell" that I have understood as a "one" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie sorry I meant ell not 1. I will change that.

Comment: Forget my first question.

Comment: One problem is how to differentiate homogeneous harmonic polynomials: What special properties do the derivatives have?